# ldfcn.h gives 0 instead of true or false

Tags: c++, linux

i have dummy.cpp

```
   #include <iostream>
     #ifndef EXPORT_API
  #define EXPORT_API __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
  #endif 
extern "C"{


using namespace std;
bool dum = true;
   

int main(){};
};
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

 
void *test = dlopen("./dummy", RTLD_NOW);

 //bool sus = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(dlsym(test , "turd"));
bool* give =(bool*) dlsym(test, "dum");

cout<<give<<"refrence";

};
```

and i compile them with
 `g++ dummy.cpp -o dummy`
`g++ main.cpp -o main -ldl`
but when i run `./exe`
i get `0refrence` and i dont know how to fix this or what the issue is i also have tried making it a function and returning it but that didn't work

Comment: Have you used `objdump` on `dummy`? Have you checked the return value of `dlopen`? A standard compile command for g++ doesn't usually create a loadable library.

Comment: got it working.
any way to use `auto` with that?

Comment: `bool *pdum=(bool *)dlsym(test, "dum"); auto dum= *pdum;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it with `gcc -shared -o dummy.so -fPIC dummy.cpp`   to get a proper so file
and if yours has a function like int foo(){} or something
use `std::invoke` in your `.so`file and then call it like

```
bool* give = (bool *) dlsym(test, "dum");
auto answr = *give;
```

where `answr` is the return val